# Extract data from uploaded file name

Tags: data

Hi there thanks for looking at my question!
I am a SharePoint n00b, as I just started using it at my new job this past week.  For context about my question - I am working in county government and I am about to tackle a large project that requires me to scan and upload hundreds of HR files.  I unfortunately cannot make scanning more efficient but I am hoping to make the uploading part more efficient.

**To my question:**
Each file scanned has a naming convention like lastName,firstName-IDNumber.PR.Tax.PP####.pdf.  Now the part after IDNumber can be different like just .Benefits or .Info, etc.  The problem is that after uploading there is a modal window that pops up and has a few unpopulated fields and yes you guessed it, I have to manually enter in those unpopulated fields BUT that info could (I think) be extracted from the file name - I know it's all there because currently I have to copy and paste it in.  I would love to just be able to upload, have the info extracted from the file name, double check the info is correct and then move on.

The caveat is that as just an end user, I don't have privelages to be able to change anything so I need to go to tech services and ask them to do it for me but I don't want to be just another person asking for their help without any idea if this can be done OR a concept of how long it would take to get done.

I'm using SharePoint on-prem and have access to add a workflow, but the templates available are not applicable to me and I cannot open SharePoint Designer as I'm blocked by the admin.

So I guess ultimately could this be done?  If so, did I explain it well enough about for our tech team to be able to understand what I need?

Thanks for your help friends!

Comment: Please indicate if you are using SharePoint Online or SharePoint on-prem (and which version). This will help folks know what additional tools you may have available.

Comment: Thanks Matthew, how would I find that info?

Comment: Well, usually the URL will tell you. If it is `mycompany.sharepoint.com` you are using SharePoint Online. If it's not then it is likely on-prem. If so, ask your IT department which version you are running.

Comment: I'm 80% sure it's not SharePoint online (I don't remember the url having sharepoint.com in it), but I'm not in office today so I will confirm tomorrow.

Comment: OK, that makes it a bit more complicated because there are not as many standard tools available. If it is on-prem, find out if they enabled any workflow tools.

Comment: I will find that out.  I'm assuming (perhaps wrongly) that I can find if they enabled workflow tools by poking around sharepoint?

Comment: Possibly, but that's a whole different question.

Comment: That's fair.  I'll message tech services in the morning and ask.  I will update the question when I find the answer

Comment: I updated my question to include that I'm using SharePoint on-prem and have access to add workflows but the templates available aren't applicable to what I need

Answer (score 0):

What I would try is:

1. Create a copy of the actual destination library including all columns.
2. Change the columns so that the metadata isn't required.
3. Create a workflow that extracts the information from the filename and populates the columns with data.
4. Then move the file to the destination library with the metadata attached.